# Need help understanding PHP documentation semantics

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I use a little bit of php to work with a database. Never used it enough to explore what it can do. Until now. I went looking at the documentation and I see a function I have used countless times. I thought I knew how to use it until the docs and now I'm baffled

```
mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

In my php that is simply

```
mysqli_query($connection, $anMySQLQuery);
```

Where I'm confused is the use of

> [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ]

What's with the [] and the comma after the opening [?

As a reader of the docs what does [, indicate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not related to php, lots of programming languages / libraries use this convention to tell us the parameter(s) beetween `[]` are optionnal.

`foo(bar[,baz])` means the function `foo` takes at least 1 argument, `bar` and an optional `baz` parameter.

Comment: Ah ok excellent. Only time i have seen [] is objective-c and there they didn't mean optional. Thanks for the quick answer. Will accept it as when it lets me

Comment: For more information, see the chapter [How to read a function definition (prototype)](http://php.net/manual/en/about.prototypes.php) in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

```
[, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ]
```

The comma is the parameter separater that will be required if passing the second parameter.

The brackets denote an 'optional' parameter, and there may be many of these.

The 'int' is the 'type' of parameter that will be accecpted.

The value 'MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT' is the default value that will be used if the parameter is not added.  (In this case, a CONSTANT).

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets (`[]`) are used to indicate optional parameters.

So the argument list should be interpreted as follows: You must provide `$link`, followed by a comma, followed by `$query`. Then you **may** add another comma and `$resultmode`. If you do not pass the third argument, it will be assigned a default value of `MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT`.

Comment: Thank you. Marked your answer up but you were just beaten to it so have to give the  check mark to Junius Rendel